# Abort chain of AJAX requests with jQuery deferred

Tags: ajax, jquery-deferred, abort

I am making a chain of AJAX calls like in the example below, which I found at http://www.dotnetcurry.com/jquery/1022/jquery-ajax-deferred-promises.

How can I adjust the code to prevent that **function B** gets called if the response from the AJAX call in **function A** is an empty JSON object array (i.e. "[ ]")? Ideally I would like to not only abort the chain of AJAX calls, but also inform the user that no result was found.

Thanks!

```
function A() {
    writeMessage("Calling Function A");
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/scripts/S9/1.json",
        type: "GET",                    
        dataType: "json"
    });
}


function B(resultFromA) {
    writeMessage("In Function B. Result From A = " + resultFromA.data);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/scripts/S9/2.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}


function C(resultFromB) {
    writeMessage("In Function C. Result From B =  " + resultFromB.data);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/scripts/S9/3.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

function D(resultFromC) {
    writeMessage("In Function D. Result From C = " + resultFromC.data);
}

A().then(B).then(C).then(D);

function writeMessage(msg) {
    $("#para").append(msg + "<br>");                 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, you could make every one of your worker functions A, B, C, D return an object that contains the response data and whether you want to continue calling the next function in the chain, whatever that may be. Something like this:

```
function A(input) {
    return $.get("/scripts/S9/1.json").then(function (response) {
        return {
            continue: response.data && response.data.length,
            data: response
        };
    });
}
```

Now you can make a promise chain by reducing an array of worker functions, and deciding in every step whether you want to continue (in which case you execute the next worker) or not (in which you simply keep returning the last valid result for the rest of the chain). I've wrapped this logic into a function `breakableChain`, for lack of a better name.

```js
function maybe() { return Math.random() > 0.25; }
function A(input) { console.log('in A:', input.data); return {continue: maybe(), data: 'result from A'}; } 
function B(input) { console.log('in B:', input.data); return {continue: maybe(), data: 'result from B'}; } 
function C(input) { console.log('in C:', input.data); return {continue: maybe(), data: 'result from C'}; } 
function D(input) { console.log('in D:', input.data); return {continue: maybe(), data: 'result from D'}; } 

function breakableChain(workers, init) {
    return workers.reduce(function (current, next) {
        return current.then(function (result) {
            return result.continue ? next(result) : result;
        });
    }, $.Deferred().resolve({continue: true, data: init}));
}

breakableChain([A, B, C, D], 'initial data').then(function (result) {
    console.log('overall:', result.data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Of course you can make a non-generic version of this that doesn't need a `continue` flag, but instead hard-codes the assumptions about each result directly into the `if` statement inside `.reduce()`. That would be shorter, but not re-usable.

The whole `{continue: true, data: result}` thing is just a convention. Your convention could also be "if the previous call returned anything, then continue, otherwise stop", the approach would be the same, but it would become impossible to return an overall result.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak for taking your time to write such a detailed answer! Unfortunately, many of the concepts in the second block are unfamiliar to me. I don't understand that code so I do not know how to apply it. Do I need the second block of code?

Comment: By the way, do you know a good source for learning about the things you make use of in the second block of code?

Comment: Of course you need that second code block, it does all the work. It's the very core of what my answer is about. I understand if you cannot wrap your head around it, it requires solid knowledge of how asynchronous code works, and of how Promises work in particular. I suspect you don't really understand your own code sample very well either. That's difficult to solve for me.

Comment: I would suggest that you read about Promises. There are literally almost infinite blog posts, tutorials, documentation (like the MDN), detailed Stack Overflow answers on all aspects of what they are and how they work. With that will come some understanding of what asynchronous code is. It will definitely take a moment if those concepts are new to you, but there is no way around doing it. Once you have a better understanding of your own code sample, concentrate on making gradual changes to it. My code is not the only way of solving your question, but hopefully it will become clearer over time.

Comment: Thanks again @Tomalak. I actually do understand the code sample I referred to. I never use code that I don't understand. I will read up on promises and hopefully understand your answer eventually :D

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: Never using a code sample you don't understand is a good thing. I might have overdone it with my answer, it's quite generic and might be more complicated than necessary for your situation. Try to modify your current code first, it's certainly not useful to make things harder harder than they are.